# Resizing a THREE.CubeGeometry at runtime

Tags: three.js

I am using Three.JS r58 and I would like to resize a CubeGeometry object on the screen.

One approach I tried is, when resizing required, to remove the effected cubes and add a new one with updated dimentions. This process works but it slows down the visualisation dramatically. I would like to know if there is a way to resize a CubeGeometry dynamically using Three.js rather than removing/adding a new one. A sample in jsfiddle is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `.scale.set(x, y, z)` on the mesh (see [this ticket](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/728)).

Initially the `scale` is set to `(1, 1, 1)` (see the constructor of [Object3D](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js), the parent class of `Mesh`).  You will want to increase those values by the percentage scale you require, in the dimensions you require.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/1046/) I increase the cube in all directions by 50 percent using `.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)`.

Comment: While scaling the Mesh obviously... er.. scales the Mesh, the problem is that then objects scale and therefore related objects coordinate system is affected. Therefore if you only wanted to scale the Geometry of object A, object B that's later added to A is also malformed by that scale. Is it really so that you cannot scale the Geometry itself? For CubeGeometry you can easily make a new geometry when needed. For loaded 3d object geometry (eg. from .stl file) that's really not an option.

Comment: I brought up this problem here (https://discourse.threejs.org/t/1021/10) and am going to release a solution in my project (https://github.com/trusktr/infamous/tree/threejs). For now, my implementation just re-creates the Geometry on size change (without affecting coordinate space of all children). In that discussion, I mentioned the idea of treating a Geometry similar to an Object3D with its own world transform. This would make sizing very fast.